# How powerful is winRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, photoshop

EDIT: So apparently the last attempt at this question was to open ended. Allow me to try again:

So I've been thinking about Microsoft's 'One Windows' vision, and I am wondering... how powerful could WinRT really be? If someone was to target only PC systems and not phones or tablets, could it be possible to port a console level game (+15GB), or programs like Chrome or Photoshop?

MAIN QUESTION: is it possible to port PHOTOSHOP to WinRT?

Comment: can the person who downvoted PLEASE HAVE THE COURTESY to explain why they did so? I mean, the question is pretty straightforward: is it possible to port PHOTOSHOP to WinRT? that's it. Damn

Comment: As one example of a rich & complex app: the new versions of Microsoft Office are running as a Universal Windows Apps. I'm not familiar with the details of Photoshop's implementation, but one feature an app like Photoshop would lose as a UWP is support for 3rd-party installable filters / plugins. There might be others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheOneWhoCould If you need to port Photoshop to any system, the first place to check will be Adobe. They might be able to help you if the code can be or is allowed for porting. I am not sure if the photoshop system architecture is publicly available for anyone to comment on its porting capabilities...

Comment: thank you for having the decency of answering the question. some people on this site are so full of themselves